# SideMenu for mvvmCross

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Tying to implement side menu for `Xamarin.iOS` app, but got warning in console:

> mvx:Warning: 0.25 No sidemenu found. To use a sidemenu decorate the
>   viewcontroller class with the 'MvxPanelPresentationAttribute' class
>   and set the panel to 'Left' or 'Right'.

Steps

1) Create base class for menu (from [sample](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/iOS-Support/XamarinSidebar/MvvmCross.iOS.Support.Sidebar))

```
public class BaseMenuViewController<T> : MvxViewController<T>, IMvxSidebarMenu where T : class, IMvxViewModel
{
    public virtual UIImage MenuButtonImage => UIImage.FromBundle("burger");

    public virtual bool AnimateMenu => true;
    public virtual float DarkOverlayAlpha => 0;
    public virtual bool HasDarkOverlay => false;
    public virtual bool HasShadowing => true;
    public virtual bool DisablePanGesture => false;
    public virtual bool ReopenOnRotate => true;

    private int MaxMenuWidth = 300;
    private int MinSpaceRightOfTheMenu = 55;

    public int MenuWidth => UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone ?
        int.Parse(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width.ToString()) - MinSpaceRightOfTheMenu : MaxMenuWidth;

    private bool UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone
    {
        get { return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone; }
    }

    public virtual void MenuWillOpen()
    {
    }

    public virtual void MenuDidOpen()
    {
    }

    public virtual void MenuWillClose()
    {
    }

    public virtual void MenuDidClose()
    {
    } 
}
```

2) Implement VisibleView (First one that will be visible)

```
[MvxSidebarPresentation(MvxPanelEnum.Center, MvxPanelHintType.ResetRoot, true)]
public partial class ContentViewController : MvxViewController<ContentViewModel>
{
    public ContentViewController()
        : base("ContentViewController", null)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Purple;
        this.ViewModel.Show<MenuViewModel>();
    }
}
```

3) Implement MenuElementViewController (SideMenu)

```
[Register("MenuViewController")]
[MvxSidebarPresentation(MvxPanelEnum.Left, MvxPanelHintType.PushPanel, false)]
public class MenuViewController : BaseMenuViewController<MenuViewModel>
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    }
}
```

4) Add presenter for SideMenu in Setup

```
protected override IMvxIosViewPresenter CreatePresenter()
{
    return new MvxSidebarPresenter((MvxApplicationDelegate)ApplicationDelegate, Window);
}
```

Expected behavior

Should see controller from point 1 with burger button

Actual behavior

Controller from point1 become visible but without burger button,
Controller from point2 not initialized,
Warning in console about missed decoration for class, but as u see they are present (also warnings deprecated and need to be updated - [check source code - searching done for correct type, but warning has old message](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/releases/5.0.0/MvvmCross-iOSSupport/MvvmCross.iOS.Support.XamarinSidebar/Views/MvxSidebarViewController.cs) )

Configuration

MvvmCross v 5.0.6

- MvvmCross
- MvvmCross.Core
- MvvmCross.Binding
- MvvmCross.iOS.Support
- MvvmCross.iOS.Support.XamarinSidebar
- MvvmCross.Platform
- SidebarNavigation

Also saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497462/mvvmcross-sidebar-navigation-for-mvvmcross-5-x) while looking for error - recheck and looks like everything is fine, but not work.

Warning log:

> mvx:Diagnostic:  0.21 Setup: Secondary end
>
> mvx:Diagnostic:  0.21 Showing ViewModel ContentViewModel
>   iOSNavigation:Diagnostic:  0.21 Navigate requested
>
> mvx:Warning:  0.23 No sidemenu found. To use a sidemenu decorate the viewcontroller class with the 'MvxPanelPresentationAttribute' class and set the panel to 'Left' or 'Right'.

I also expect to see breakPoint stop in `ViewDidload` for `MenuViewController` when call `this.ViewModel.Show<MenuViewModel>();` but it's never triggered, in same moment model for this controller created.

Can someone advice what was done incorrect?

---

EDIT

I was able to setup [new empty project with sidebar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1GU18BxUf8hTUk1azJEZGFKNG8/view?usp=sharing) and it's work as expected. But same code not work in my current projects - I don't know why decorated attributes are not read as expected....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spend 2 days to figure out the reason - the issue related to detection and parsing decorator attributes.

I have few projects that share codebase between each other, and due to some reason 
`[MvxSidebarPresentation(MvxPanelEnum.Left, MvxPanelHintType.PushPanel, false)]`

is not taken in to account if it placed in shared project but not in project itself. In same moment

```
[MvxSidebarPresentation(MvxPanelEnum.Center, MvxPanelHintType.ResetRoot, true)]
[MvxSidebarPresentation(MvxPanelEnum.Center, MvxPanelHintType.ResetRoot, true, MvxSplitViewBehaviour.Master)]
[MvxSidebarPresentation(MvxPanelEnum.Center, MvxPanelHintType.PushPanel, true, MvxSplitViewBehaviour.Detail)]
```

works as expected.

Workaround -> subclass shared menuClass (with `MvxPanelEnum.Left`) in each project where it should be used.

Not sure if this issue related to mvvmCross lib or to Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

That trace is triggered by this piece of code in the `MvxSidebarViewController`.

```
    protected virtual void SetupSideMenu()
    {
        var leftSideMenu = ResolveSideMenu(MvxPanelEnum.Left);
        var rightSideMenu = ResolveSideMenu(MvxPanelEnum.Right);

        if (leftSideMenu == null && rightSideMenu == null)
        {
            Mvx.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Warning, $"No sidemenu found. To use a sidemenu decorate the viewcontroller class with the 'MvxPanelPresentationAttribute' class and set the panel to 'Left' or 'Right'.");
            AttachNavigationController();
            return;
        }

        // ...
    }
```

So Mvvmcross is failing to resolve the SideMenu view controllers marked with the attributes you have used above. I'd suggest removing all of the MvvmCross nugets and nuking the *bin* and *obj* folders.

Possibly try adding a constructor to the `MenuViewController` might help.

If all that fails I'd try building the classes exactly how they are in the test project, I noticed your `ContentViewController` doesn't inherit from a base class like it does in the project. I know this shouldn't really be relevant but what I've found from my experiments with the sidebar classes is it's very particular with the setup of ViewControllers and nested view controllers.

I did away with the MvvmCross siderbar nuget altogether and just used the XamarinSidebar nuget directly, I used `MvxSidebarViewController` as a starting point to create my own implementation, I wasn't particularly keen on the attribute setup and I like to handle the navigation myself rather than use `ShowViewModel` or the new navigation system.

Hope some of that helps.

Comment: thanks - I already try to remove/add/update reinstall lib, recreate all classes, rename, clean, remove bin/ and obj/ folders, ful clean of project - result every time same.... In same moment i copy-paste code in separate project and it just work.. Looks like problem with decoration attribute detection (pleasee see my edit with sample link)

Comment: also add/remove constructors, direct subclass from Mvx classess not help

Comment: Interesting might be a Xamarin bug, try googling the attributes detection.

Comment: already started... if i found root cause - i will post it here, thanks (honestly not very familiar with c#)

Comment: If all else fails you could just do what I did and make your own implementation using the XamarinSidebar nuget.

Comment: preffered is mvvmCross solution, thus i have project with mvvmCross as main lib and so we targeted to use mvvmCross navigation approach, but of cause if i not found any solution i will try it

Comment: Yes, I'm saying you could write your own MvvmCross navigation code wrapped around the sidebar stuff. Good luck!